# Installing Nachos 3.4 Error cast from void* to int loses precision

Tags: c, linux, gcc, 64-bit, nachos

I'm trying to install Nachos 3.4, I'm using Linux 64 bit and I have a problem, the error is `casting from void* to int loses precision [-fpermissive]`. I have searched many times and tried many ways such: using `intptr_t`, `long`, `,static_cast<int>` and so on. But they didn't work, I can not use C or C++ library like `stdint.h`, `cstdint.h`, `iostream`, ...
I also intend to use a cross-compiler but I have no clue. Please help me, thanks very much.
[image]

Comment: You need to look at the definition of `func`. If the function takes an `int`, then no amount of casting in the function call is going to fix the problem.

Comment: @user3386109 This is the source code of Nachos so I don't think I can change the definition of `func`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nachos is 32-bit only.  You are essentially trying to compile it for 64-bit, and it won't work; it is written to work only on [ILP32 data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).  It also requires [GCC 3.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/), as it expects literal string constants to be mutable, and later GCC versions do not support that option, `-fwritable-strings`, at all: the code may compile without the flag, but the binaries segfault.

In essence, nachos is horribly outdated.

Your best bet is to install [Debian 3.1r8](https://archive.org/details/debian-31r8) in a virtual machine (virtualbox for example), and compile and run Nachos there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried again on Linux 32 bit and it has worked.